# Can I override a group policy setting as a machine admin?

Tags: windows

Group policy prevents several configuration settings on my Windows 7 / Vista machines. Since my domain account is a member of the local Administrators group on these boxes, is there still a way to override them locally?

For instance, GP prevents changing the power management option "Turn off the display" (even changing it from cmd fails: POWERCFG -X -monitor-timeout-ac 60  => "An unexpected error condition has occurred.  Unable to perform operation.  You may not have permission to perform this operation.")

Even when logging on with a local account and not the domain account, it's not possible to change the setting anymore ..

Comment: You probably would have better luck on superuser.com, possibly serverfault, but this is definitely not programming related. If you are trying to accomplish this with code, I would suggest clarifying your question to indicate that as well as providing what you have already.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Posted my question on superuser.com.

Comment: Just delete this one then, would you?

Comment: Oh, and it's already been migrated from superuser to serverfault.

Comment: @MichaelKohne I couldn't find it on serverfault - unless it is this one? http://serverfault.com/questions/65011/how-can-i-override-group-policy-using-a-local-administrator-account

Answer (score 2):

While @bnkdev is correct, there are ways around it, of course.

For example, since you have admin rights, you can change the permissions on the specific policy-related Registry keys (e.g. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft...) such that the SYSTEM account cannot change them (deny write), but you still can.

Also, it's been a while, but I have used a little program called KillPol.exe (see [this blog post](http://windowsxptoolstips.blogspot.com/2008/01/get-admin-privileges-on-windows-xp.html) for info and possible download), which will allow you to override the GPO settings at least temporarily. (Note, however, I don't know if or how well it works on Vista & Win7, which have very different implementations of the Registry.)

Answer (score -1):

Group Policy always trumps local policy.